# Angular: Disable button on click after required fields are filled in the form

Tags: angularjs

I need to disable the submit button after clicking on the button to prevent multiple submissions but before the it has to ensure that the required fields are filled.

I tried

```
<body ng-app="ngToggle">
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<form name="newUserForm">
<input type="text" required>
<input type="text" required>
<input type="text">
<button ng-click="disableClick()" ng-disabled="isDisabled" 
ng-model="isDisabled">Disable ng-click</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>

angular.module('ngToggle', [])
.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.isDisabled = false;
$scope.disableClick = function() {
    alert("Clicked!");
    $scope.isDisabled = true;
    return false;
}
}]);
```

but this will only disable the button without any validation

Comment: You don't have any required fields in your code, and no form. It's good that you're trying to minimize the amount of code, but we're going to need a bit more.

Comment: There can't be any validation if there is nothing to validate

Comment: What do you expect ng-model on a button to do?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I get what you mean/want so I'll try to help and come up with some code - which is obviously missing but if it wasn't missing the necessary code, you'd have the solution :)

First, you'll have to properly write your form:

```
<form name="newUserForm" ng-submit="disableClick(newUserForm.$valid)" novalidate> 
    <input type="text" name="input1" ng-model="form.input1"  required>
    <input type="text" name="input2" ng-model="form.input2"  required>
    <input type="text" name="input3" ng-model="form.input3"> //not required
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="isDisabled">Disable ng-click</button>
</form>
```

so what we've got here, which you're missing:

1. You did name your form, but you're missing a submit, in the form as ng-submit or the button with type="submit", which will submit the form and that's when the validation happens
2. In order for Angular to validate your inputs, they need to have ng-model, otherwise it will not validate (HTML5 validation would, but read on)
3. I've added novalidate so we tell the browser "Hey, we need this validated but not by you, so do nothing", and Angular takes over
4. And last but not least, Angular adds a couple of properties to the form (see more here: [Angular form Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)), $valid being one of them, which is set to true when all validated inputs are valid.

So this sums up the changes you needed to do to your form.

As for the Javascript part, there is just one small change:

```
$scope.disableClick = function(valid) {
  if(valid && !$scope.isDisabled) {
    $scope.isDisabled = true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I guess the change is obvious, but I'll explain anyway - check that newUserForm.$valid (boolean) and if it's true (meaning form has passed validation) disable this button.

Of course, you'll have to add checks not to run the code on any type of submits and not just disabling the button (which can easily be re-enabled via Dev Tools), so that's why I added !$scope.isDisabled to the if statement.

Hope this answers your question :)

P.S. Here's a running demo in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9kZg9JLjmrCFD0zE5gad?p=preview)